# Determining the Fundamental Matrix Using Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Determine $\mathit{e}^{At}$ by using generalized eigenvector method to find a fundamental matrix of $x'=Ax$ with $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 5 &-4  &0 \\ 
>  1&0  &2 \\ 
>  0& 2 &5 
> \end{bmatrix}$.

I just want to know whether my solution is okay?

I found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda_{1}=0$ (multiplicity 1) and $\lambda_{2}=5$ (multiplicity 2).

I found the eigenvector of $\lambda_{1}$ to be $v_{1}=(-4,-5,2)$ and the eigenvector of $\lambda_{2}$ to be $v_{2}=(-2,0,1)$.

I used the generalized eigenvector property to find $v_{3}$, where $v_{2}=(A-\lambda_{2}I)v_{3}$. I got $v_{3}=(1/2,1/2,1)$.

So then $\mathit{e}^{At}=\begin{bmatrix}
-4 &-2  &\frac{1}{2} \\ 
 -5&0  &\frac{1}{2} \\ 
 2& 1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$. Is this okay?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your $e^{At}$ does not have $t$ in it, so something is wrong.

Comment: Mathematica gives me
$$
e^{At} = \left.\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 t & -4 t & 0 \\
 t & 0 & 2 t \\
 0 & 2 t & 5 t \\
\end{array}
\right)\right.
$$

Comment: I think I forgot a few things in my solution. The fundamental matrix is actually $\mathit{e}^{At}=P\mathit{e}^{Jt}$, where $P=\begin{bmatrix}
-4 &-2  &\frac{1}{2} \\ 
 -5&0  &\frac{1}{2} \\ 
 2& 1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &5  &1 \\ 
0 &0  & 5
\end{bmatrix}$ is the Jordan canonical form. What do you think?

Comment: I am not sure. You may want to compute $e^{Jt} $explicitly and multiply with $P$ to see if you obtain the correct form for $e^{At}$.Since $J$ is upper-diagonal, it should not be too hard to compute $e^{Jt}$.

Comment: Its $e^{tA}=Pe^{tJ}P^{-1}$...

Comment: @Isham According to my notes, $P\mathit{e}^{Jt}P^{-1}$ is for the state transition matrix which is also a fundamental matrix, right?

Comment: yes the matrix $e^{tA}$ I checked some of your work and i have foun no errors except for that matrix. You just forgot the $P{-1}$  in the formula.

Comment: @Math1000 That can’t be right either, since it doesn’t involve $e^{5t}$. You’ve got $tA$ there, not $e^{tA}$.

Comment: @Isham If you're saying that my $P$ and $J$ are correct, I thank you very kindly for checking this for me!

Comment: I checked the eigen values ..thats correct. And checked some eigen vectors.You made mistakes when you evaluated $e^{tA}$

Comment: @amd Apparently I used `MatrixExponential` instead of `MatrixExp`. `MatrixExp[A*t]` gave $$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{RootSum}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-25 \text{$\#$1}-40\&,\frac{e^{t \text{$\#$1}} \text{$\#$1}^2-5 e^{t \text{$\#$1}} \text{$\#$1}-4 e^{t \text{$\#$1}}}{3 \text{$\#$1}^2-25}\&\right] \\
 \text{RootSum}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-25 \text{$\#$1}-40\&,\frac{e^{t \text{$\#$1}} \text{$\#$1}-5 e^{t \text{$\#$1}}}{3 \text{$\#$1}^2-25}\&\right] \\
 2 \text{RootSum}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-25 \text{$\#$1}-40\&,\frac{e^{t \text{$\#$1}}}{3 \text{$\#$1}^2-25}\&\right] \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

Comment: And that just doesn't seem right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Math1000 Beats me. I get the correct answer with `MatrixExp[t {...}]`, entering the matrix explicitly in the expression. Maybe your value for the variable `A` or `t` has gotten clobbered along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{At} = P e^{Jt} P^{-1}$

and

$e^{Jt} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{J_1 t} && 0 \\ 0 && e^{J_2 t} \end{bmatrix}$

Firstly, as $J_1 = 0$, $e^{J_1t} = 1$ .

Now, if we open taylor series of exponential around $\lambda_2$

$e^{xt} = \sum \frac{e^{\lambda_2t}}{n!}(xt-\lambda_2t)^n $

$e^{J_2 t} = \sum \frac{e^{\lambda_2 t}}{n!}(J_2t-\lambda_2 I t)^n$

Now,

$J_2t-\lambda_2I t = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1t \\ 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Note that,

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1t \\ 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}^n = 0, for: n>1$

Then,

$e^{J_2 t} = e^{\lambda_2 t} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} + e^{\lambda_2 t} \begin{bmatrix} 0 && t \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_2 t} && te^{\lambda_2 t} \\ 0 && e^{\lambda_2 t}   \end{bmatrix}$

And finally if your eigenvectors are correct, you have:

$e^{At} = P^{-1} e^{Jt} P = \begin{bmatrix}  -4 && -2 && 1/2 \\ -5 && 0 && 1/2 \\ 2 && 1 && 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && e^{5 t} && te^{5t} \\ 0 && 0 && e^{5t} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  -4 && -2 && 1/2 \\ -5 && 0 && 1/2 \\ 2 && 1 && 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$